# jQuery trigger events under 2 dynamically generated layers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, cocoon-gem

I've been using jquery to trigger events on dynamically generated text fields using `on`, `delegate` and alike, just as described in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6658774/2540204)  That works very well, but when I try to add another dynamically generated layer, I can't get the action to trigger.  So for example

**Dynamically adding people to a list is fine**

```
| People List
|
| 1) Name _______
|
|  ---------------------
| |Click to add a person|
|  ---------------------
|
```

If I want to dynamically add people to a list and trigger an alert each time the focus is on the text box the following works fine for that

```
$('div.people-list').delegate('input.name', 'focusin', function(){
  alert("textbox focusedin");
});
```

**The Problem Comes when I have a list of lists.**
So say I wanted to have a dynamic list of multiple buses with a dynamic list of multiple passengers.  Something like below.

```
| Bus List
|
|  1)  Bus ID_______
|   
|   | Passenger List
|   |
|   | 1) Name _______
|   |
|   |  ---------------------
|   | |Click to Add a Person|
|   |  ---------------------
|
|  ------------------
| |Click to Add a Bus|
|  ------------------
```

Under those circumstances, it seems that my above javascript using `delegate` is not sufficient.  What do I need to add to trigger events on this sort of nesting?

In the even that it matters (though I don't think it would), I'm using rails and the cocoon gem for the field dynamics.

Comment: Use `$(document).delegate` and try!! and add relevant code regarding how you are adding dynamic controls!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao Sorry for the delay.  As you probably expected, your solution worked perfectly.  Feel free to write up your comment as an answer so I can properly credit you.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dynamically adding controls it will be good if you refer them with `document` to delegate to them. So you can try below code.

```
$(document).delegate('input.name', 'focusin', function(){
  alert("textbox focusedin");
});
```